# How innodb resume transactions?

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb

I am recently reading the InnoDB code and need to write some code on it.
I know in S2PL, a blocked transaction will be resumed after the conflicted transaction finishes. However, I am not sure how InnoDB resumes transactions after a block, is there a thread which handle this kind of work? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When a lock is needed but can't be granted, the lock is entered into a lock queue at the page level. When any lock is released, the releasing transaction searches the queue and grants the next newly non-conflicting locks from the queue. See `lock_rec_enqueue_waiting`, `lock_rec_dequeue_from_page`, `lock_grant`, etc. from `storage/innobase/lock/lock0lock.c` in the MySQL source code.